# How much take time for launch Superset Through Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-superset

I started the launch process using [docker-compose up](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose/#:%7E:text=previous%20command%20with%3A-,docker%2Dcompose%20up,-%2C%20and%20wait%20for) command, still processing from last 3 hours. Is it usually taking the time.?

This is processing in visual studio terminal.
[image]

Comment: Pretty confident shouldn't take that time. Could you post any logs? or additional information about your environment?

Comment: Hi @GonzaloMatheu, I have edited and attached the screenshot.